# How to design an app that is heavy in modal view?

Tags: ios, mobile-application

I am currently designing an iOS app that is supposed to digitize a paper form. The problem here is that the task requirements makes the modal view nested. IE: A client (EG: Starbucks) has many sites (EG: Queens Street Branch) and each site has many contacts (Supervisors for each shift). How do I make it possible to create/update/retrieve/delete easily without using a lot of screen?

Comment: This may sound quip but I'm being serious. Start with hiring a designer or somebody familiar with designing UX.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a basic hierarchy and you are asking about navigation.
These concepts are already laid out in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Navigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH53-SW1). I suggest you read it through. Specifically the part about making one choice per screen until they arrive at their destination.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible to do so "without using a lot of screen?" It sounds as if you are using drill-downs with the modal.

Most importantly you need to separate your thinking from the existing paper form and start thinking about how time sheets will be utilized on a mobile device.

1. A modal pops up for Starbucks (originating from a list, or a map of a neighborhood, or whatever)
2. App user selects a branch and gets a drill-down of positions and names which he can act upon. (Change entered hours, update shifts, change locations, etc...)

Your users will think of the data in a multitude of ways, you need to anticipate this and provide screens for these actions.

```
As a user I want to find who's working as head barista at <location x>
As a user I want to see everyone who is working <shift a> at <location x>
As a user I want to see the hours of <supervisor b> for <time period t>
```